# How should I organize shader system with opengl

Tags: opengl, shader, 3d-engine

I was thinking about:

Having a main shader which will be applied to every object of my application, it will be used for projection, transformation, positionning, coloring, etc..

And each object could have their own extra shader for extra stuff, for example a water object definitely needs an extra shader.

But there is a problem, how would I apply 2 or more shaders into one object ? Because I'll need to apply the main shader + object's own shader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be really nice if OpenGL (or Direct3D!) allowed you to have multiple shaders at each vertex / fragment / whatever stage, but alas we are stuck with existing systems.

Assume you've written a bunch of GLSL functions. Some are general-purpose for all objects, like applying the modelview transformation and copying texture coords to the next stage. Some are specific to particular classes of object, such as water or rock.

What you then write is the **ubershader**, a program in which the main() functions at the vertex / fragment / whatever stages do nothing much other than call all these functions. This is a template or prototype from which you generate more specialised programs.

The most common way is to use the preprocessor and lots of #ifdefs around function calls inside main(). Maybe if you compile without any #defines you get the standard transform and Gouraud shading. Add in #define WATER to get the water effect, #define DISTORT for some kind of free form deformation algorithm, both if you want free-form deformed water, #define FOG to add in a fog effect, ...

You don't even need to have more than one copy of the ubershader source, since you can generate the #define strings at runtime and pass them into glCompileShader.

What you end up with is a lot of shader programs, one for each type of rendering. If for any reasons you'd rather have just one program throughout, you can do something similar on newer systems with GLSL subroutines.

These are basically function pointers in GLSL which you can set much like uniforms. Now your ubershader has 1, 2, ... function pointer calls in the main() functions. Your program just sets up #1 to be standard transform, #2 to be rock/water/whatever, #3 to be fog, ... If you don't want to use a stage, just have a NOP function that you can assign.

While this has the advantage of only using one program, it is not as flexible as the #define approach because any given pointer has to use the same function prototype. It's also more work if say WATER needs processing in multiple shaders, because you have to remember to set the function pointers in every one rather than just a single #define.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can have multiple shaders attached to a shader stage, as long as only one of them has a `main()` function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if I did understand correctly my extra shaders should only be functions without main(), and I should call them through the main shader's main() and manage with preprocessors.

Comment: Yes. For a very simple example, https://github.com/apertus-open-source-cinema/stereo_cam_check and have a look at renderer.py and video_frag.glsl. (The code is inlined instead of calling separate functions though.)